# how to achieve a good and clean render in blender?

Tags: rendering, animation, baking, unity, lighting

hello everyone it's my first time posting a subject in the Blender community.
i have to notice that i never used Blender except for modeling objects because i'm an indie game developer and the engine that i work with it is Unity. anyway recently i made a 3D backgammon game for mobile platform and i want to make a small animation to introduce it. i watched you tube tutorials mostly for texturing and lighting and learned many things but after a couple of days practicing about light and texturing i didn't understand light in CG art very well it seems is too experimental. i modeled these backgammon board with Blender and import and rendered them in unity engine. how can i achieve good and clean lighting like image number 3? i rendered one of my backgammon boards in Blender but the result wasn't really good i cant balance the light and shadow.[image]
it would be great if you give some  tips or guide me to specific tutorials

Comment: With 2.7x it's as simple as a hemispheric lamp with disabled shadow and Blender Renderer, but in 2.8x you must, alas, use NPR node

Comment: How about cycle is it possible to use NPR node for it?

Comment: Yes it is, RV Binary.